# Casting Object to a Pair

Tags: java, object, casting

I am trying to get my "equals" method to work but am having trouble. This is supposed to be easy but I am new to this. I thought I had to cast otherOject to a pair in order to be able to use .fst and check if the pairs are equal, however I am having difficulty "casting" properly. Any help would be much appreciated. I have the following methods:

```
public void setFst(T1 aFirst)
{
    fst = aFirst;
}

public void setSnd(T2 aSecond)
{
    snd = aSecond;
}

public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    Pair aPair = (Pair)otherOject; //--------> ???

    if(otherObject.fst.equals(this.fst) && otherObject.snd.equals(this.snd))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors I am getting:

```
./Pair.java:84: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable fst
location: class java.lang.Object
                if(otherObject.fst.equals(this.fst) && otherObject.snd.equals(this.snd))
                              ^
./Pair.java:84: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable snd
location: class java.lang.Object
                if(otherObject.fst.equals(this.fst) && otherObject.snd.equals(this.snd))
                                                                  ^
```

Comment: Why are you using `otherObject` instead of `aPair`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major problem is that after you have cast, you are comparing with the original `otherObject`, which still is an instance of the `Object` class, rather than the variable on the Left hand side of your assignment `aPair` which has the type `Pair`

So, this should get you going:

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    Pair aPair = (Pair)otherOject; //--------> ???

    if(aPair.fst.equals(this.fst) && aPair.snd.equals(this.snd))
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Be careful here though.  What you are doing is called unchecked casting.  Your compiler might warn you about it.  You don't know whether the object being passed to your equals method really can be cast to a `Pair` - it has to be an instance of `Pair` or a subclass of `Pair` for that to be a valid action.  So, your cast might fail at runtime if, for instance, you pass a `String` or `Integer` object into the method.

***EIT***

@NathanHughes's [more complete answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27992091/838992) to this question shows you how to check the casting (using instanceof keyword), so I won't repeat it here.

I recommend the Oracle java tutorial docs for this kind of thing. Check [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) for classes and subclasses - the very end is about how to cast and check if it is valid to cast.

Comment: You're exactly right, I am passing strings and integers and getting a runtime error. Any idea on how I would avoid this? The instructions are "return true if this pair is equal to aPair". How would I allow comparison between strings and ints if I am doing unchecked casting, is there a way to "check" my casting? I apologize for my java incompetence.

Comment: Everyone has to learn.  @NathanHughes answer just now shows you how to check the casting (using instanceof keyword).  I recommend the Oracle java tutorial docs for this kind of thing.  Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html for classes and subclasses - the very end is about how to cast and check if it is valid to cast

Answer (score 1):

This isn't that easy, this has more pitfalls than you'd think.

Your equals method has to allow for having objects belonging to classes other than the class you're writing it for. You have to do is check to see if the argument is also a Pair:

```
if (otherObject == null) return false;
if (otherObject.getClass() != Pair.class) return false;
```

After this check is passed you can cast safely, and assign the cast object to a new local variable:

```
Pair otherPair = (Pair)otherObject;
```

then use the fields on otherPair for your equals check. At this point you're done with the otherObject parameter and the rest of the equals method shouldn't reference it anymore.

the whole thing would look like

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    if (otherObject == null) return false;
    if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
    Pair otherPair = (Pair)otherObject;
    return otherPair.fst.equals(this.fst) && otherPair.snd.equals(this.snd);
}
```

assuming that fst and snd are not allowed to be null. Calling the equals method on a null member will cause a NullPointerException. To avoid the NPE if fst or snd are null, check if the members are null before calling equals on them:

```
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
    // check if references are the same
    if (this == otherObject) return true;
    // check if arg is null or something other than a Pair
    if (otherObject == null) return false;
    if (getClass != otherObject.getClass()) return false;
    Pair otherPair = (Pair)otherObject;
    // check if one object's fst is null and the other is nonnull
    if (otherPair.fst == null || this.fst == null) {
        if (otherPair.fst != null || this.fst != null) return false;
    }
    // check if one object's snd is null and the other is nonnull
    if (otherPair.snd == null || this.snd == null) {
        if (otherPair.snd != null || this.snd != null) return false;
    }        
    // each member is either null for both or nonnull for both
    return ((otherPair.fst == null && this.fst == null) || otherPair.fst.equals(this.fst)) 
    && ((otherPair.snd == null && this.snd == null) || otherPair.snd.equals(this.snd));
}
```

This last bit is annoying to write, IDEs will generate this stuff for you. Here's what Eclipse generates:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Pair other = (Pair) obj;
    if (fst == null) {
        if (other.fst != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!fst.equals(other.fst))
        return false;
    if (snd == null) {
        if (other.snd != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!snd.equals(other.snd))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Remember to implement hashCode too.

Comment: Thank you! For some reason, this code returns "true" when two strings have the same characters but in a different order. How would I fix this? Again I am sorry for my lack of java knowledge.

Comment: @Ronon: that is really weird. are you sure it's this method or a problem where you didn't implement hashCode? also if T1 or T2 have problems with their equals method you'll see a problem here.

Comment: Test whether (ZUeEuHVWxXWi,12) is equals to (ZUeEuHVWxXWi,12): PASS
Test whether (ZUeEuHVWxXWi,12) is equals to (UeEuHVWxXWi,12): FAIL                      (this is what is displayed when I run the test program, the strings are not equal but it returns that they are. I'm sure it's probably an issue with another section of my code. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: @Ronon: you could make a Pair object that took generic type params for fst and snd and test it separately.

Answer (score 0):

Best to do

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object otherObject) {
  if (otherObject instanceof Pair) {
    Pair otherPair = (Pair)otherObject;
    return otherPair.fst.equals(fst) && otherPair.snd.equals(snd)) 
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Put a space between your `if` and the opening parenthesis, please!  It is like people have become so worried about wasting spaces that they are trying to make the code less readable by making all `if`, `do ... until`, and `while` blocks look like functions.  Insane!

Comment: Favor putting curly braces on the same line as the conditional portion of the `if` statement.  It allows you to get more code on the screen, and it reduces the chance that someone (which often means ourselves) puts a statement between the two, _making your entire block non-conditional_.

Comment: Unfortunately, this returns a null pointer exception. I believe this is a valid solution however there must be an error somewhere in my code...

Comment: @RononJason If it throws a NPE, it's because you permit `fst` or `snd` to be null.  Perhaps you shouldn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `otherObject` is an instance of `Object` and there is no `fst` on the `Object`. Need to change to `aPair.fst.equals`.

Comment: I think you meant to say that there is no `fst` on the Object, as the `fst` is only on the `aPair`

Comment: Not a problem, typos happen all the time.